Magento 2 : Admin Login - Your current session has been expired
I get the Your current session has been expired. error when trying to login.
In the admin_user_session table the session_id column which should be null is populated with a single character which means that sessions do not match
How has this happened and how do I fix it?
Magento 2.4.3
PHP 7.4

ok so the comment for the session id says "Deprecated: Session ID value no longer used " but this appears to be false, I've changed varchar(1) to varchar (128) and it works

This is the proper solution for this one.
Step-1 : find admin/security/session_lifetime in table core_config_data. if not exist create one and set value to 86400
Step-2 : clean cache (remove var/cache).
If you want same using CLI, then run this command.

php bin/magento config:set admin/security/session_lifetime 86400


php bin/magento cache:flush

